# Error Deploying .NET Core Application to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying a .NET core application from GitHub to an Azure App Service and receiving the following error:

> Feeds used:
>       https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json   D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "D:\home\site\repository\src\MY_APP"
>   --configuration Release --no-dependencies --build-base-path "D:\home\site\repository\src\artifacts"   Microsoft (R) Build Engine
>   version 15.1.0.0   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
>   reserved. **MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
>   [D:\home\site\repository\src\MY_APP\MY_APP.xproj]   Switch:
>   --build-base-path**

As far as a I [can tell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-build), *build-base-path* is a valid parameter.

This application was deploying fine.  In fact, I even tried to redeploy the last good deployment and it too is failing now.

Here is the project.json:

```
{


"buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-rverbio-457D3F4C-1C63-4A4C-8D65-5EA4FA4EE5F9",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core": "0.1.0-preview",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    //"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory": "3.13.7",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions": "2.0.0-beta6-207211625",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        }

      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "config.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "precompile": [
      "powershell -f Download-Secrets.ps1"
    ],
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "npm run build"
    ],
    "postpublish": [
      "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

### Update

A colleague of mine created a global.json with the following contents and deployments are working!

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
    }
}
```

Comment: What core sdk version are you targeting, and do you have a global.json pointing to it?

Comment: I added the project.json to the question.  There is no global.json.

Comment: If you share a sample repo that repros the issue I will try to see what's happening at publish time in Kudu

Comment: @DavidEbbo, we added a global.json and deployments are working again.  Thanks for pointing us in the right direction.